# Custom Font Typeface for CSS Style

Tags: android, html, css, xml

I have a WebView in my Android Application to display the textual content. The CSS Properties are implemented using the following code:

```
public static final String CSS_PROPERTIES = "<style>body{width:100%;margin:0;}
  img {max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style>";
```

I tried to change the code to the following syntax but nothing helped:

```
public static final String CSS_PROPERTIES = "<style type='text/css'>@font-face { font-family: nafees; src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/nafees.ttf'); } 
  body p {font-family: nafees; width:100%;margin:0;}
  img {max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style>";
```

I wish the font applied to the webView.

This CSS_PROPERTIES string is then implemented as:

```
contentText = new StringBuilder().append(AppConstant.CSS_PROPERTIES)
.append(contentText).toString();
```

Then

```
webEngine.loadHtml(contentText);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code.

```
webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);

        String pish = "<html><head><style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: sanfranciscotext_bold;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/sanfranciscotext_bold.otf\")}body {font-family: sanfranciscotext_bold;font-size: medium;text-align: justify;}</style></head><body>";
        String pas = "</body></html>";
        String myHtmlString = pish + "Hello This is test for Font" + pas;
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Add font resource in assets folder like this way.
[image]

Output like :

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! WIth your help and support, I was able to resolve my issue. Thanks!